# El indice estaba fuera del intervalo, debe ser un valor no negativo e inferior

Tags: vb.net

Estoy intentando insertar una variable del tipo string al gridview "GridviewCitar", la variable del tipo string la traigo de forma correcta pero al querer colocar ese registro en el gridview me arroja el error
Este es mi codigo:

````
            If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
                IDEstadoIntranet = row.Item("IDEstado").ToString().Trim
                busObjVehiculosEstadosUnigisIntranet.TraerVehiculoEstadosUnigisIntranet2(dsEstadosIntranet, IDEstadoIntranet)
                EstadoUnigis = dsEstadosIntranet.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item("UniEstado").ToString().Trim
                GridViewCitar.Rows(1).Cells(9).Text = EstadoUnigis
            End If
        Next```
````

Comment: y existe esa fila y esa celda?

Comment: Por qué 9? Dónde defines que haya al menos 10 celdas?? (Seguro es base cero como muchos conteos en programación)

Comment: si, es celda 9 ya que cuando cargo el DataSet lo cargo con variados datos, y es en la fila 9 del DataSet donde debo insertar un dato distinto al que viene en el DataSet. Además tambien probe con la celda 0 como empiezan los conteos en programacion pero arrojaba el mismo error, siendo celda 0 o 1 o 2, etc...